# installing E5504 processor, should i use cooler paste?

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, installation

I just got a E5504 processor and intel heatsink. In the paper it do not show anything about if I should apply cooling paste before installing the heat sink? Is this something we used to do in the past? or should i just apply some anyhow even though its not shown in the catalog?

There was nothing coming with the boxed processor, but i have some from the past.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As i recall, most OEM heatsinks come with a thermal pad, and that should usually be sufficient. *Some* heatsinks come with thermal paste with a plastic covering which may need to be removed.

IF there's already a thermal solution, *DO NOT* use that at the same time as your own thermal paste. I'd suggest using whatever the heatsink comes with first (its probably good enough) and switching over to thermal paste *only* if its insufficient - which i doubt, unless you intend to do something silly like overclock a server.

EDIT: for reference, the thermal paste application on intel heatsinks looks like this

[image]

It'll spread out when applied and should be sufficient for most needs.

Comment: on my heat sink, theres theses 3 lines of something that looks like metal, is this the thermal pad you mention?

Comment: A picture would help. Most of what i've seen has a single large copper core, fins around that and a white pad as a thermal interface.

Comment: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51rA3pzm5LL._SL500_AA300_.jpg  This is the heat sink - at the bottom of it theres 3 small lines, 5x20 mm of something alittle darker than the other metal, maybe 1mm thick. I think its thermal paste but not sure

Comment: Edited in an image of the thermal paste application on a stock intel heatsink.